# Rewrite to new URL and 301 the old page to the new URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have products.php which I'm trying to change into /europe-cell-phone/. I've made a rewrite rule to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^europe-cell-phone/$ products.php [L]
```

However I also need to 301 the old page (products.php) to /europe-cell-phone/. I'm trying to do this with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^products.php$ http://www.eurobuzz.com/europe-cell-phone/ [R=301,L]
```

However of course when I go to products.php expecting to be redirected I hit an infinite redirect loop, is there any solution to this? Never encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your products.php to products-new.php
and create two rules like these:

RewriteRule ^europe-cell-phone/$ products-new.php [L]

RewriteRule ^products.php$ products-new.php [R=301,L]

Comment: not the best solution but oh well.

Comment: Don’t forget to escape the dot.

Comment: The second (external redirect) directive would need a slash prefix, or use an absolute URL, or set `RewriteBase /` - otherwise you'll get a malformed redirect. But there is no need to create a `products-new.php` file - see [@Gumbo's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/66664/368326)

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the original request in `THE_REQUEST` as `REQUEST_URI` already might have been changed by a rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /products\.php
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ /europe-cell-phone/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^europe-cell-phone/$ products.php [L]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

for rewrite in apache, you write them like this:  RewriteRule *pattern* *substitution*

So the first rule you list matches "europe-cell-phone" and replaces it with "products.php"

Your second rule seems to do the opposite.  I think you may need to switch things around in your first rule.

Comment: My first rule means that when I go to domain.com/europe-cell-phone/ it produces the page products.php.

Comment: (which is what I want)

Comment: sorry, i'm confused. is URL to products.php domain.com/europe-cell-phone/products.php, or is it domain.com/products.php?

Comment: I want domain.com/europe-cell-phone/ to display domain.com/products.php, and I want people who go to domain.com/procucts.php to go to domain.com/europe-cell-phone/

Comment: make your second rule more specific.  when your second rule gets rewritten by apache, it triggers your first, which triggers your second, etc, etc.  include domain.com in the pattern of your second rule; not just ^products.php$